# Nodemcu does not connect to phone wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, nodemcu

All welcome.

I'm trying to connect nodemcu to the phone's wifi.

And nodemcu can't do it. But sometimes after several reboots she does it. Also if i use my old phone - nodemcu connects perfectly! Why?

My "new" phone: Fly FS504 Cirrus 2

My old phone: Fly IQ4504 Quad.

My code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char *ssid =  "Just my SSID";     

const char *pass =  "Some password";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
       Serial.begin(9600);
       delay(10);

       Serial.println("Connecting to ");
       Serial.println(ssid); 

       WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
       while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
          {
            // stack here (only with new phone)
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
          }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 
}

void loop() 
{      

}
```

Comment: Does it crash? If you're on a breadboard I guess that's the reason. You could try to explicitly `WiFi.disconnect()` before attempting to connect, the esp8266's wifi is a bit buggy sometimes.

Comment: @SimSon, hmm.. Just add Wifi.disconnect() before WiFi.begin()?

Comment: @SimSon, thanks! It's working! I spent a lot of time for this problem. Have a nice day :)

Comment: glad to hear. So did my workaround "fix" your problem? If yes, I'd form it into an answer so you can close this question

Comment: @SimSon, yeah, do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience the esp8266's wifi is a little bit buggy sometimes. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the esp auto-connecting to known networks, but I managed to work-around this issue by explicitly `WiFi.disconnect()`ing from any potential network right before calling `WiFi.begin()`.

Another thing that I noticed several times is that the esp can be easily disturbed when connected to a breadboard, in special when wifi is in use (in this case the esp might even crash). There must be some bad interferences, I guess.